# i have to write "(Ft³)" on label from resource file. please help me

Tags: c#

Actually i have to write "(Ft³)" on label from resource file.

When i write in string as hard code "ft\u00B3" then its convert on label as "Ft³", but i want to access from resource file. so please help.........

thnx

Answer (score 1):

Just paste "Ft³" into the resources designer - not "ft\u00B3"

It gets stored as:

```
<data name="Ftcubed" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Ft³</value>
</data>
```

in the .resx file